# discord.py | add role to user if they have keyword in custom status

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to add a role to a user if they have a keyword in their custom status, but I can't make it work

Here is my code:

```
    import discord
    from discord.ext import commands
    intents = discord.Intents.all()
    intents.members = True
 
bot=commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix,case_insensitive=True,intents=discord.Intents.all())
    async def check_activity():
      await bot.wait_until_ready()
      role = discord.utils.get(bot.guild.roles, name = "Premium")
      for member in bot.get_all_members():
        for s in member.activities:
          if isinstance(s, discord.CustomActivity):
              status = s
          if "status" in status:
              await member.add_role(role)
    await asyncio.sleep(20)
    
    bot.loop.create_task(check_activity())
bot.run("TOKEN", reconnect = True, bot = True)
```

I'm not receiving anything in the shell/console.
Are their any errors in my code?
Help would be greatly appreciated! I'm using discord.py version This is a bot just for a community that I'm in. The version I'm using is Version 1.7.3

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. Also, please [edit] your post to include what version of discord.py are you using.

Comment: `get_all_members` isn't really a good idea in this case. You're trying to add a single role (Why `bot.guild`? Isthere only one?) to every member in possibly other guilds. Also you need `str(status)` - the conversion isn't done automatically for you. Also see what @TheFungusAmongUs said - you should never be accessing the loop in any modern version. Use `discord.ext.tasks` instead.

Comment: @EricJin this is just a bot for a community I'm in. The version has now been included

Comment: Try my suggestion. Does using `str(status)` work? Try doing `print(str(status))` and seeing what it gives you for every member.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event listener `on_member_update`.

There you can check if `after.status` is equal to the status you want.

if this is = true; then you can add the role.

It goes into greater detail here:

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member%20update#discord.on_member_update

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member%20status#discord.Member.status